# Proving iff - Mean curvature and Weingarten Map

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, curvature, minimal-surfaces

The parametrized surface:
$$\textbf{R}\supset{U}\ni(x,y)\longmapsto (x,y,f(x,y))\in\textbf{R}^3$$
defined by the graph of a smooth function $z=f(x,y)$ 
I know that the Weingarten map:$$L:=II\circ I^{-1}$$ equals the Guassian curvature.
Now I'm interested in calculating that the trace of L (which I believe is the mean curvature of this surface) and using that to prove that the surface has mean curvature zero if and only if $f$ satisfies the minimal surface equation, namely $$H=\frac{(1+f_y^2)f_{xx}-2f_xf_yf_{xy}+(1+f_x^2)f_{yy}}{2(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^{3/2}}$$
I have attached what I have accomplished so far- I am not sure how the proof part of this is supposed to work, although I believe this is because I may have screwed up the calculations.[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your computation. When computing the first fundamental forrm you should get
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix}
  E & F  \\
  F & G 
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1+f_x ^2 & f_x f_y  \\
  f_x f_y & 1+f_y ^2 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The second fundamental form is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  L & M  \\
  M & N 
 \end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{fx ^2+f_y ^2-1}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{xx} & f_{xy}  \\
  f_{xy} & f_{yy} 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
And the shape opratator $dn_p$ (I didn't use L since L is the element in position 11 of the second fundamental form) is:
\begin{equation} 
dn_p
=
\frac{1}{(1+fx ^2+f_y ^2)^(3/2)}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{xx}(1+f_y ^2)-f_x f_y f_{xy} &  f_{xy}(1+f_y ^2)-f_x f_y f_{yy} \\
  f_{xy}(1+f_x ^2)-f_x f_y f_{xx} &  f_{yy}(1+f_x ^2)-f_x f_y f_{xy}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Now the mean curvature is defined as:
\begin{equation}
H=-\frac{1}{2} Tr(dn_p)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
H=-\frac{1}{2 (1+f_x ^2+f_y ^2)^(3/2)} ( f_{xx}(1+f_y ^2)-2 f_x f_y f_{xy}+f_{yy}(1+f_x ^2) )
\end{equation}